# Clipping or masking a raster by individual polygons in a feature layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have a shapefile (polygon) layer consisted of four polygons and I have a raster. I want to calculate statistics for every raster part which is beneath any of these polygons.

I tried the following code:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy.sa import *


os.chdir("E:/Reza/2015/spring and summer/1 oct/test")
inRaster="E:/Reza/2015/spring and summer/1 oct/test"+os.sep+"Band_1.tif"
objects="E:/Reza/2015/spring and summer/1 oct/test"+os.sep+"objects.shp"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(objects,["*"]) as cursor:
    for row in sorted(cursor):
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(inRaster, row[1])
```

but when I run, it says:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Rezars/Desktop/1", line 10, in <module>
        outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(inRaster, row[1])
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy   \sa\Functions.py", line 7030, in ExtractByMask
        in_mask_data)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy    \sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
        result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7026, in Wrapper
    out_raster)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 498, in <lambda>
      return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
     RuntimeError: Object: **[![Error in executing tool][1]][1]**
```

The table of my feature layer with its polygons is like this:

[image: content table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGIS, a tool you can use is Extract by Mask, part of the Spatial Analyst extension (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm).

If you don't have that extension, another way about it is to use your polygons, one by one, as analysis masks; you'd have to change the raster analysis mask variable for every polygon - see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/mask.htm.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My feature layer (polygon) has many features(rows). When I use Extract By Mask It gives me a mask which is from all rows but I want every output for every row of polygon layer

Comment: @Khandan You have to use Extract by Mask with only one polygon selected in the polygon layer, and repeat the process for each polygon. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have assumed that when you say "non-rigid" you are meaning non-rectangular.

I think [Clip (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009n000000) is the correct tool to use.

However, I suspect that you have not specified a `ClippingGeometry`:

> If you are using a feature class as the output extent, you have the
>   option to clip the raster by the extent of the feature class or by its
>   polygon perimeter.
>
> - NONE —The raster dataset is clipped based on the minimum bounding rectangle of the feature class.
> - ClippingGeometry —The raster dataset is clipped based on the perimeter of the polygon shape.